# Copying contents of columns with Field calculator in Qgis

Tags: qgis

I have to split the content of a column into 2 differents columns using the QGIS Field Calculator. Basically, my table is something like that:
[image]

Basically I have to work with *descriptio* column omitting characters from 1-12 and then copy next 8 characters (in this case "AgilisSi") into the *PresLACAGI* column.

The other element to copy  is the final number in *descriptio* column, ranging from 1 to 3 characters. Possibly the best is thing would be a syntax that reproduces in *CodiClapa* column the number after ": ", including the space in the syntax.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `field calculator`, check `Update existing field` and select column from drop down and type in the Expression window for:

1. PresLACAGI:  `substr(descriptio,12,8)`
2. CodiClapa: `right(descriptio,3)`